# How does a Toyota communicates with MyToyota?

Tags: toyota

I got a new Toyota RAV4 Hybrid (2021) and it has the ability to connect to the MyToyota service.

**What, technically, does the communication?**

When pairing the car with MyToyota, I was asked to do several manipulations to send the odometer value to MyToyota. It was eventually successful and the car is paired with the service.

This suggests a built-in SIM card (that would also be used for the emergency call the car does when there is an accident, or that I can do by pressing a button on the roof).

On the other hand, my phone was already connected to the car, both via BT and via Wi-Fi.

I would like to retrieve information about the car through the Toyota service but I do not know whether it is updated

- continuously via a built-in SIM
- when my phone is connected through BT
- when my phone is connected via WiFi (the phone creates an ad-hoc access point)

In general, I wonder what the Wi-Fi is for (I use Google Auto and not the built-in navigation)

Answer (score 1):

When you are connected to wifi the information is distributed through the internet. OnStar is used for this purpose also.